# How to Join based on whether the date RANGE of table 1 intersects with the date range of table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, range

```sql
left join Mars_Crater_Names n1 on t1.ID=n1.ID and t1.StartDate between n1.StartDate and n1.EndDate
```

The problem is that the start date of a record in `T1` may not fall between the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of the record its being matched to in `N1`. So the query typed is not what I want.

#### N1

| ID | CraterName | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID4 | Phoenix | 04090000 | 18220000 |
| ID4 | Aurora | 18230000 | 19780000 |

#### T1

| ID | Stellar_Phase | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID4 | Drying | 18120000 | 18330000 |
| ID4 | Normalizing | 18330000 | 19780000 |

So to conclude, `Phoenix` should be joined to `Drying`, because their ranges intersect, and though `Aurora` does intersect with `Drying`, `Phoenix` is the first to do so. `Aurora` is joined with `Normalizing` because it is the first and only to intersect with `Normalizing`.

```sql
left join Mars_Crater_Names n1 on t1.ID=n1.ID and t1.StartDate between n1.StartDate and n1.EndDate
```

This is what I tried but its far off from what I need.

Comment: Intersection condition is `.. t1.start < t2.end AND t2.start < t1.end ..`. Intersect+Adjacency condition uses the same expression with soft comparing operators. PS. Use INNER JOIN and not LEFT one..

Comment: I think you have an extra 1 in the `StartDate` of `Normalizing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akina already gave you the solution for the intersect problem.
In order to only use the first match you can use the [`row_number()` window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), which produces a unique number for a `partition` (similar to a `group by`)

```sql
select * from (
    select
        t1.id as t_id,
        t1.stellar_phase,
        t1.startdate t_startdate,
        t1.enddate t_enddate,
        n1.id as n_id,
        n1.CraterName,
        n1.startdate n_startdate,
        n1.enddate n_enddate,
        row_number() over (partition by t1.stellar_phase order by n1.StartDate) rn
    from stellar_phase t1
    left join Mars_Crater_Names n1 on t1.ID=n1.ID 
    and t1.StartDate <= n1.EndDate
    and n1.StartDate <= t1.EndDate
) x 
where rn = 1
```

With the following setup script

```sql
create table stellar_phase(
  ID    varchar(5),
  Stellar_Phase varchar(20),    
  StartDate  integer,
  EndDate    integer
);

create table Mars_Crater_Names(
  ID    varchar(5),
  CraterName varchar(20),   
  StartDate  integer,
  EndDate    integer
);

insert into Mars_Crater_Names(
  ID,
  CraterName,   
  StartDate,
  EndDate
) values 
('ID4', 'Phoenix',  04090000,   18220000),
('ID4', 'Aurora',   18230000,   19780000);

insert into stellar_phase(
  ID,
  stellar_phase,    
  StartDate,
  EndDate
) values 
('ID4', 'Drying',   18120000,   18330000),
('ID4', 'Normalizing',  18330000,   19780000); -- changed the start date
```

The select yields

| t_id | stellar_phase | t_startdate | t_enddate | n_id | CraterName | n_startdate | n_enddate | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID4 | Drying | 18120000 | 18330000 | ID4 | Phoenix | 4090000 | 18220000 | 1 |
| ID4 | Normalizing | 18330000 | 19780000 | ID4 | Aurora | 18230000 | 19780000 | 1 |

---

Note that I modified the test data slightly, since it did not match your description.

[See the full script on DB Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bnpMiEnjTyQT12vQGEnVPo/0)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answers, Jens, it really helped.

Comment: The customary way of saying "the answer helped" is to upvote the answer. If it solved the problem. And if the answer completely solves the answer accept it using the check mark, so that others can see the question is satisfactory answered.